# How can an array be grouped by two properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

**Ex:**

```
const arr = [{
  group: 1,
  question: {
    templateId: 100
  }
}, {
  group: 2,
  question: {
    templateId: 200
  }
}, {
  group: 1,
  question: {
    templateId: 100
  }
}, {
  group: 1,
  question: {
    templateId: 300
  }
}];
```

**Expected Result:** *`const result = groupBy(arr, 'group', 'question.templateId');`*

```
const result = [
  [{
    group: 1,
    question: {
      templateId: 100
    }
  }, {
    group: 1,
    question: {
      templateId: 100
    }
  }],
  [{
    group: 1,
    question: {
      templateId: 300
    }
  }],
  [{
    group: 2,
    question: {
      templateId: 200
    }
  }]
];
```

---

**So far:** I am able to group the result by a single property using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
function groupBy(arr, key) {
  return [...arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    const propVal = currentValue[key],
      group = accumulator.get(propVal) || [];
    group.push(currentValue);
    return accumulator.set(propVal, group);
  }, new Map()).values()];
}

const arr = [{
  group: 1,
  question: {
    templateId: 100
  }
}, {
  group: 2,
  question: {
    templateId: 200
  }
}, {
  group: 1,
  question: {
    templateId: 100
  }
}, {
  group: 1,
  question: {
    templateId: 300
  }
}];

const result = groupBy(arr, 'group');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to pass a callback function instead of a property name, this allows you to do the two-level-access easily:

```
function groupBy(arr, key) {
  return Array.from(arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    const propVal = key(currentValue),
//                  ^^^^            ^
          group = accumulator.get(propVal) || [];
    group.push(currentValue);
    return accumulator.set(propVal, group);
  }, new Map()).values());
}
```

Now you can do `groupBy(arr, o => o.group)` and `groupBy(arr, o => o.question.templateId)`.

All you need to do for getting to your expected result is group by the first property and then group each result by the second property:

```
function concatMap(arr, fn) {
  return [].concat(...arr.map(fn));
}
const result = concatMap(groupBy(arr, o => o.group), res =>
  groupBy(res, o => o.question.templateId)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

@Bergi's answer is really practical but I'll show you how building a multi-value "key" can be possible using JavaScript primitives – don't take this to mean Bergi's answer is *bad* in anyway; in fact, it's actually a lot better *because* of it's practicality. If anything, this answer exists to show you how much work is saved by using an approach like his.

I'm going to go over the code bit-by-bit and then I'll have a complete runnable demo at the end.

---

**compound data equality**

Comparing compound data in JavaScript is a little tricky, so we're gonna need to figure out a way around this first:

```js
console.log([1,2] === [1,2]) // false
```

I want to cover *a* solution for the multi-value key because our entire answer will be based upon it - here I'm calling it a `CollationKey`. Our key holds some value and defines its own equality function which is used for comparing keys

```js
const CollationKey = eq => x => ({
  x,
  eq: ({x: y}) => eq(x, y)
})

const myKey = CollationKey (([x1, x2], [y1, y2]) =>
  x1 === y1 && x2 === y2)

const k1 = myKey([1, 2])
const k2 = myKey([1, 2])
console.log(k1.eq(k2)) // true
console.log(k2.eq(k1)) // true

const k3 = myKey([3, 4])
console.log(k1.eq(k3)) // false
```

---

**wishful thinking**

Now that we have a way to compare compound data, I want to make a custom reducing function that uses our multi-value key to group values. I'll call this function `collateBy`

```
// key = some function that makes our key
// reducer = some function that does our reducing
// xs = some input array
const collateBy = key => reducer => xs => {
  // ...?
}

// our custom key;
// equality comparison of `group` and `question.templateId` properties
const myKey = CollationKey ((x, y) =>
  x.group === y.group
    && x.question.templateId === y.question.templateId)

const result =
  collateBy (myKey) // multi-value key
            ((group=[], x) => [...group, x]) // reducing function: (accumulator, elem)
            (arr) // input array
```

So now that we know how we want `collateBy` to work, let's implement it

```
const collateBy = key => reducer => xs => {
  return xs.reduce((acc, x) => {
    const k = key(x)
    return acc.set(k, reducer(acc.get(k), x))
  }, Collation())
}
```

---

**Collation data container**

Ok, so we were being a little optimistic there too using `Collation()` as the starting value for the `xs.reduce` call. What should `Collation` be?

What we know:

- `someCollation.set` accepts a `CollationKey` and some value, and returns a new `Collation`
- `someCollation.get` accepts a `CollationKey` and returns some value

Well let's get to work!

```
const Collation = (pairs=[]) => ({
  has (key) {
    return pairs.some(([k, v]) => key.eq(k))
  },
  get (key) {
    return (([k, v]=[]) => v)(
      pairs.find(([k, v]) => k.eq(key))
    )
  },
  set (key, value) {
    return this.has(key)
      ? Collation(pairs.map(([k, v]) => k.eq(key) ? [key, value] : [k, v]))
      : Collation([...pairs, [key, value]])
  },
})
```

---

**finishing up**

So far our `collateBy` function returns a `Collation` data container which is internally implemented with an array of `[key, value]` pairs, but what we really want back (according to your question) is just an array of values

Let's modify `collateBy` in the slightest way that extracts the values – changes in **bold**

```
const collateBy = key => reducer => xs => {
  return xs.reduce((acc, x) => {
    let k = key(x)
    return acc.set(k, reducer(acc.get(k), x))
  }, Collation()).values()
}
```

So now we will add the `values` method to our `Collation` container

```
values () {
  return pairs.map(([k, v]) => v)
}
```

---

**runnable demo**

That's everything, so let's see it all work now – I used `JSON.stringify` in the output so that the deeply nested objects would display all content

```js
// data containers
const CollationKey = eq => x => ({
  x,
  eq: ({x: y}) => eq(x, y)
})

const Collation = (pairs=[]) => ({
  has (key) {
    return pairs.some(([k, v]) => key.eq(k))
  },
  get (key) {
    return (([k, v]=[]) => v)(
      pairs.find(([k, v]) => k.eq(key))
    )
  },
  set (key, value) {
    return this.has(key)
      ? Collation(pairs.map(([k, v]) => k.eq(key) ? [key, value] : [k, v]))
      : Collation([...pairs, [key, value]])
  },
  values () {
    return pairs.map(([k, v]) => v)
  }
})

// collateBy
const collateBy = key => reducer => xs => {
  return xs.reduce((acc, x) => {
    const k = key(x)
    return acc.set(k, reducer(acc.get(k), x))
  }, Collation()).values()
}

// custom key used for your specific collation
const myKey =
  CollationKey ((x, y) =>
    x.group === y.group
      && x.question.templateId === y.question.templateId)

// your data
const arr = [ { group: 1, question: { templateId: 100 } }, { group: 2, question: { templateId: 200 } }, { group: 1, question: { templateId: 100 } }, { group: 1, question: { templateId: 300 } } ]

// your answer
const result =
  collateBy (myKey) ((group=[], x) => [...group, x]) (arr)

console.log(result)
// [
//   [
//     {group:1,question:{templateId:100}},
//     {group:1,question:{templateId:100}}
//   ],
//   [
//     {group:2,question:{templateId:200}}
//   ],
//   [
//     {group:1,question:{templateId:300}}
//   ]
// ]
```

---

**summary**

We made a custom collation function which uses a multi-value key for grouping our collated values. This was done using nothing but JavaScript primitives and higher-order functions. We now have a way to iterate thru a data set and collate it in an arbitrary way using keys of any complexity.

If you have any questions about this, I'm happy to answer them ^_^

Comment: Thank you very much Naomik for the effort and excellent explanation put into your answer. The step-by-step explanation is very clear, consice and friendly – it did help me understand even better my requirement itself and how it can be solved with different approaches. A `+1` is just not enough so thanks again `:)`.

Comment: Ricky, I'm delighted to have helped ^^

Comment: Wow, very thorough

Answer (score 1):

@Bergi's answer is great if you can hard-code the inputs.

If you want to use string inputs instead, you can use the `sort()` method, and walk the objects as needed.

This solution will handle any number of arguments:

```js
function groupBy(arr) {
  var arg = arguments;
  
  return arr.sort((a, b) => {
    var i, key, aval, bval;
    
    for(i = 1 ; i < arguments.length ; i++) {
      key = arguments[i].split('.');
      aval = a[key[0]];
      bval = b[key[0]];
      key.shift();
      while(key.length) {  //walk the objects
        aval = aval[key[0]];
        bval = bval[key[0]];
        key.shift();
      };
      if     (aval < bval) return -1;
      else if(aval > bval) return  1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
}

const arr = [{
  group: 1,
  question: {
    templateId: 100
  }
}, {
  group: 2,
  question: {
    templateId: 200
  }
}, {
  group: 1,
  question: {
    templateId: 100
  }
}, {
  group: 1,
  question: {
    templateId: 300
  }
}];

const result = groupBy(arr, 'group', 'question.templateId');

console.log(result);
```