# Is it possible to control how object property names get converted to strings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, properties, es6-proxy

I'm interested in creating an object that can handle keys of different types separately instead of casting them all to strings. I'm wondering if there's a way to do this with proxies or any other relatively new JavaScript features. If I do something like

```
const handler = {
    get: function(target, name) {
        return typeof(name);
    }
};
const proxy = new Proxy({}, handler);
```

and then try to access `proxy[1]` it returns `string` as the type. I understand why this is happening, but I'm curious if there's any way to hook into this type conversion and control it. I know that I could override `Number.prototype.toString`, but I would like to *only* modify this behavior when the property name is being processed. Ideally I would want something analogous to this.

```
const handler = {
    convertPropertyNameToString: function(target, name) {
        return `${typeof(name)}--${name}`;
    }
};
const proxy = new Proxy({}, handler);
```

I just want to control the conversion of the property names into strings for a specific object. If there's not a straightforward way to do it, then I'm also open to creative hacks.

Comment: So you're saying if something did `proxy[someObject]` you'd want to be able to implement custom logic to convert `someObject` into a string specifically for the case where it is used on `proxy`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It doesn't have to be a proxy necessarily though, anything what allow for that would be great. I just assumed that a proxy was the most likely answer.

Comment: have you seen [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which accepts object-based keys?

Comment: @naomik, thanks, I wasn't aware that `Map` objects could except keys of different types. Is there any way to implement that same sort of functionality in a custom class?

Comment: @Ivanna sure. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43129575/633183) we make a custom key-value data type. The example there uses a list of pairs, but a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) would provide much faster lookups

Comment: @naomik The part that I'm really interested in is overriding the `[]` access though. Can this be implemented in a custom class?

Comment: @Ivanna no, you can't override `[]` that way. See Logan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

With normal property access, e.g. `foo.bar` and `foo[thing]`, the key is converted to a string before the object itself even knows there is an access coming. The `get` trap on a proxy only gets access to it after than point, so it is guaranteed that a string or Symbol.

If you're interested, you can see that [in the spec for property access](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation) where on step (6) it is converted to a string. The logic to actually access the property does not happen until much later and has no knowledge about where the stringified key came from.

The best you could do is use your own function, e.g. `proxy.readKey(name)` where obviously `name` can be any value. As mentioned in the comments, this is similar to the interface used for ES6 `Map` instances.